# Strange behaviours of MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

In my DB I've a table defined as follow:

[image: 1]

I've noticed 2 strange behaviours (v 6.0):

**1)**

Exporting this table from mysql workbench menu I get **[this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a789)**, where I have:

> `sex` enum('M','F') DEFAULT NULL,

from [mysql Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) I read:

> If an ENUM column is declared to permit NULL, the NULL value is a valid value for the column, and the default value is NULL. If an ENUM column is declared NOT NULL, its default value is the first element of the list of permitted values.

and:

> `birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,

that I declared as NOT NULL.

**2)**

I've tried this query :

> "insert into users(name) values('mark');"

the insert works in mysql workbench and not in sqlFiddle.
I expected some kind of error from mysql WB but I reveive just warnings:

> 1 row(s) affected, 5 warning(s):
>
> 1364 Field 'surname' doesn't have a default value
>
> 1364 Field 'birth_date' doesn't have a default value
>
> 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value
>
> 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value
>
> 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value

Am I missing something or are they some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, I'd say. There's no default set for the specific columns. How comes MySQL Workbench generates a default clause then? Please file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com to get this fixed.